# Row Wise Operation in R with multiple Conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with following layout:

```
id |conv |diff  
----
1 | 0 | 0  
1 | 0 | 3  
1 | 0 | 45  
1 | 1 | 9  
1 | 0 | 40  
1 | 1 |34  
1 | 0 | 43  
1 | 0 | 7  
2 | 0 | 0  
2 | 1 | 5  
2 | 0 |0  
2 | 1 |45  
2 | 1 |40
```

I need to add a counter in a such a way that :

1. when the id changes or previous value of conv = 1 the counter should reset to 1
2. when the id is same and the diff is less than 10 the counter shall give the preceding counter value.
3. when the id is same and the diff is greater than 10 the counter shall be incremented by +1.

The output I am looking for is :

```
id |conv |diff | counter
----
1 | 0 | 0  | 1  
1 | 0 | 3  | 1
1 | 0 | 45 | 2   
1 | 1 | 9  | 2   
1 | 0 | 40 | 1 
1 | 1 | 34 | 2  
1 | 0 | 43 | 1  
1 | 0 | 7  | 1  
2 | 0 | 0  | 1  
2 | 1 | 5  | 1  
2 | 0 | 0  | 1  
2 | 1 | 45 | 2  
2 | 1 | 40 | 1
```

The for loop solution is :

```
for(i in 2:nrow(raw_data)){
  raw_data$counter[i]<- ifelse(raw_data$id[i]==raw_data$id[i-1] & conv==0,
        ifelse(raw_data$diff> 10 & conv == 0,raw_data$counter[i-1] +1,raw_data$counter[i-1])
          ,1)}
```

I am aware of the increase in time due to 'for' loop. Looking for a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, counter := cumsum(c(TRUE, (diff > 10)[-1])),
         by =  .(id, grp = cumsum(shift(conv, fill = conv[1L])))]
df1
#    id conv diff counter
# 1:  1    0    0       1
# 2:  1    0    3       1
# 3:  1    0   45       2
# 4:  1    1    9       2
# 5:  1    0   40       1
# 6:  1    1   34       2
# 7:  1    0   43       1
# 8:  1    0    7       1
# 9:  2    0    0       1
#10:  2    1    5       1
#11:  2    0    0       1
#12:  2    1   45       2
#13:  2    1   40       1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
What does '1L' stands for ?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar  It is just an integer representation, i.e. `class(1L)` vs `class(1)`

Comment: Ohk...What if instead of 1 as a tag in conv column there is a string such 'salecomplete'

Comment: @AbhishekKumar  In that case we will create a logical vector i.e. `conv == 'salecomplete'` and then wrap it with `shift`, also instead of `fill = conv[1L]`, it would be `fill=1` or so

Comment: Adding to the question. Let's say I would like to remove the rows which do not give me conv = 1  by the the end of the id change. For my example the rows with diff equals to 43 and 7 shall be removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146365/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-akrun).